# How to Derive a Double Angle Identity.

Tags: trigonometry

How does one derive the following two identities:
$$\begin{align*}
\cos 2\theta &= 1-2\sin^2\theta\\
\sin 2\theta &= 2\sin\theta\cos\theta
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Is the first one right?

Comment: whoops mistyped, editing now

Comment: In my experience, a very large percentage (if not all) of trigonometric identities can be deduced from the addition formulas, $\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta$ and $\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta$.

Comment: It seems everyone below is proving that $\cos2\theta=1−2\sin^2\theta$, which is what the OP wrote first. Why did you change it?

Comment: @MTurgeon Just a typo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hints:

For the $\cos 2\theta$ formula, use the sum identity (with $x=y=\theta$)
$$
\cos(x+y)=\cos x\cos y - \sin x\sin y,
$$
followed by the Pythagorean identity $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x $.

For the $\sin 2\theta$ formula , use the sum identity (with $x=y=\theta$)
$$
\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y +\sin y\cos x.
$$

---

Or, for the $\cos2\theta$ formula and $0<\theta<\pi/2$, consider the diagram:

[image]

We have
$$
\cos\theta ={ {1+\cos2\theta}\over\sqrt{2+2\cos 2\theta}};
$$
whence
$$
\sqrt 2\cos\theta=\sqrt{1+1\cos\theta},
$$
or,
$$
2\cos^2\theta= 1+1\cos2\theta
$$
From this, we have
$$
2-2\sin^2\theta=1+\cos2\theta,
$$
or
$$
\cos2\theta =1-2\sin^2\theta.
$$

(Having this in hand, we could also use the diagram to derive the formula for $\sin2\theta$.)

Comment: May I ask how you made this graphic?

Comment: @bgins Using the Javascript library [JSXgraph](http://www.jsxgraph.org/).

Comment: Thank you! I've been wishing for this!

Comment: @David Mitra Can you give me the multiple angle formula? I haven't found them in any website.

Answer (score 6):

$e^{i\theta}$ means the point with angle $\theta$ on the unit circle. Euler formula tells us that $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta$. Then 
$e^{i2\theta}=\cos^2 \theta-\sin^2 \theta+2i\sin \theta\cos\theta$. Also, we know $e^{i(2\theta)}=\cos 2\theta+i\sin 2\theta$. Compare the real and imaginary parts, and you get the desired result.

All I assume is that you know Euler formula.

Comment: This is the easiest way to remember/derive it, but obviously one needs to know what complex numbers are.

Answer (score 2):

The first one follows from:

$$\cos 2\theta = \cos(\theta +\theta) = \cos \theta \cos \theta - \sin \theta \sin \theta = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta .$$ Now use the fact $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta =1.$

The second one follows from 
$$ \sin 2\theta = \sin(\theta +\theta) = \sin \theta \cos \theta + \cos \theta \sin \theta. $$