# Using the unit circle to prove the double angle formulas for sine and cosine?

Tags: trigonometry

How do you use the unit circle to prove the double angle formulas for sine and cosine?

Comment: I'd suggest deriving the formula for sums of angles.

Comment: Use complex numbers.

Comment: I once saw a direct geometric proof of $\cos\,u=2\cos^2 u-1$, but I don't remember where I saw it...

Comment: @J.M. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126894/how-to-derive-a-double-angle-identity/126898#126898) is one geometric proof of $\cos 2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta$.

Answer (score 11):

Look at this figure:

[image: sinus2]

Comment: Ingenious -- but the unit circle is mostly decoration here, isn't it?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I’d agree with you. If you wanted to make more use of the unit circle, you could draw the diagram with angle $2\alpha$ beginning on the $x$-axis so that $\cos(2\alpha)$ and $2\sin^2\alpha$ ran parallel to the $x$-axis and so that $\sin(2\alpha)$ ran parallel to the $y$-axis. Or, you could use the the above diagram and the just-described diagram to make use of the unit circle entirely.

Comment: The picture seems to show the particular example when $\alpha = \pi/6$. A similar set up clearly works when $\alpha \le \pi/4$. It's not all clear from the answer how to extend this for larger $\alpha$. Hence the -1.

Comment: @AaronDall: This figure works for arbitrary $0<\alpha<{\pi\over4}$. When ${\pi\over4}<\alpha<{\pi\over2}$ the value of $\cos(2\alpha)$ is negative, and another figure is needed.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one possibility. Say we want to find $\sin 2\theta$ and $\cos 2\theta$. Draw the unit circle in an ordinary $x$-$y$ coordinarte system, and also introduce a new coordinate system $x'$-$y'$ that has been turned $\theta$ *clockwise* around the origin. It is important that the unit circle in the $xy$ system and in the $x'y'$ system is the same:

[image: (a diagram)]

The relation between the two coordinate systems is
$$ x' = x\cos\theta - y\sin\theta \qquad
 y'=x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta $$

The point $P$ on the diagram has coordinates $(x,y)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ in the $xy$-system, but in the $x'y'$ system is is $2\theta$ above the $x'$-axis and so its coordinates there must be $(x',y')=(\cos2\theta, \sin2\theta)$. Substituting this into the known relation between the coordinate systems yields:
$$ \cos2\theta = (\cos \theta)^2 - (\sin\theta)^2 \qquad
\sin2\theta = \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) + \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$

Comment: How did you produce your diagram? Did you draw it with pen and then scan it?

Comment: I drew it with a pen, photographed it with a digital camera, and then cleaned it up (for background and contrast) in Gimp.

Comment: How did you get the relations x′=xcosθ−ysinθ, y′=xsinθ+ycosθ?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially Christian Blatter's proof, with some minor differences, but I like the area interpretation that this one employs, and the historical connection.  It also explains a bit more the connection of Christian Blatter's proof with the circle.  This version gives the double-angle formula for $\sin$ only.

A right triangle with hypotenuse $1$ and angle $\theta$ has area $\frac{1}{2}\cos\theta\sin\theta.$  Four such triangles together have area $2\cos\theta\sin\theta.$ Arrange the four right triangles to form a kite-shaped figure.

[image]

The two diagonals of the kite-shaped figure (represented by solid lines) are perpendicular, and the area of the figure equals half the product of their lengths.  But one diagonal has length $1$ while the other has length $2\sin2\theta$.  The double-angle formula for $\sin$ follows.

My interest in this proof is partly historical.  Inscribe a regular $n$-gon in the unit circle.  Let $\ell_n$ be the length of a side of the $n$-gon.  This $n$-gon can be broken into $n$ isosceles triangles with side lengths $1,$ $1,$ $\ell_n.$

[image: inscribed polygon with n sides]

Now form a regular $2n$-gon from $n$ kite-shaped figures.

[image: inscribed polygon with 2n sides]

The diagonals of these kite-shaped figures are $1$ and $\ell_n$.  The area of this $2n$-gon is therefore
$$
A_{2n}=\frac{n\ell_n}{2}.
$$
By repeatedly doubling the number of sides, $A_{2n}$ becomes an increasingly accurate approximation of $\pi.$  This is the method for estimating $\pi$ devised by Liu Hui around 263 AD.  He started with $n=6$ $(\ell_6=1)$ and applied five doublings.  In doing this, Liu Hui needed to compute $\ell_{2n}$ from $\ell_n.$  This can be done using the formula
$$
\ell_{2n}^2=2-\sqrt{4-\ell_n^2},
$$
which is essentially the half-angle formula (since $\ell_{2n}=2\sin\theta$ and $\ell_n=2\sin2\theta$), but which Liu Hui derived using the Gougu Theoerem (Pythaogorean Theorem).  Chinese geometry of that era apparently did not employ the notion of angle, so the connection with the double-angle and half-angle formulas is ahistorical.  Obviously the modern algebraic notation is also ahistorical.

Answer (score 1):

Compute lengths of the thick line segments in the figure below in two different ways.[image]