# Why is $\sin(t)\cos(t)$ equal to $\frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I know that $\sin(t)\cos(t)$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)$ but I do not understand why, please explain it to me!

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136774/using-the-unit-circle-to-prove-the-double-angle-formulas-for-sine-and-cosine) has some explanations "from the first principles".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin 2t =\sin (t+t)= \sin t \cos t+ \cos t\sin t =\ldots$.

Comment: This is just solving a mystery by appealing to a bigger mystery )

Comment: Although who knows, maybe the problem was indeed in making this connection...

Comment: @Dan Shved: Yes, I hope that if OP don't know $\sin(x+y)$, he will ask this.

Comment: This was actually a good answer, since I didn't thaugt about that formula.

Answer (score 3):

A visual proof by applying Ptolemy's Theorem.

[image]

Imagine the circle as shown with diameter $1$. Then, by applying Ptolemy's theorem on the cyclic quadrilateral $B'DC'D'$ we have $B'D \times C'D' + C'D \times B'D' = B'C' + DD'$, equaling $2 \sin(t)\cos(t) = \sin(2t)$. To see why $D'D = \sin(2t)$, notice the triangle $D'DE$.

Answer (score 0):

Complex number solution
$$
\cos t = \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}
\\
\sin t = \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}
\\
\sin t\cos t = \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}\cdot\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}
= \frac{e^{i2t}-e^{-i2t}}{4i}
= \frac12 \frac{e^{i2t}-e^{-i2t}}{2i} = \frac12 \sin(2t)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\triangle ABC$ be the isoceles triangle with sides $AB=AC=1$ and $\angle BAC=2t$. Let $AD$ be the altitude of the base side $BC$. Then the area of the triangle can be computed in two ways.

$(ABC)=\frac12 BC AD=\frac12 (2\sin t)\cos t=\sin t\cos t$

and

$(ABC)=\frac12AB\,AC\sin(\angle BAC)=\frac12\sin(2t).$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Lets suppose the larger triangle is an isoceles triangle with its vertex at the origin.  The legs are of lenght 1 (and it has been inscribed in the unit circle).  It has been bisected into two congruent right triangles.

We will say that the larger triangle has a vertex angle of $2t$, and each of the smaller triangles have a measure t at that vertex.

The lenght of the segment that bisects the isosceles triangle (the border between red and green) has lenght $\cos t$ each of the right triangles have legs of $\sin t$ opposite the angle.

The area of the each of these is then $\frac 12 \sin t\cos t$ and together their area is $\sin t\cos t$

The lenght of the blue line is $\sin 2t$  Using that as the height at $1$ as the base gives the area of the large tringle as $\frac 12 \sin 2t$

We have now calculated the same area by two different methods and they must be equal.

$\frac 12 \sin 2t = \sin t\cos t$

The area of the large triangle is $\frac 12 \sin t$

Answer (score -1):

We now that: $$\sin(2t)=\frac{1}{2}\sin t\cos t/:\frac{1}{2}$$ Now we have: $$\frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)=\sin t\cos t$$