# Why is 2 $\cdot$ $\sin(\alpha)$ $\cos(\alpha)$=$\sin(2\alpha)$?

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-physics

I am solving a physics problem involving a 2-dimensional throw. However, I have hit a bump trying to understand

$$2\cdot \sin(\alpha)\cdot\cos(\alpha)=\sin(2\alpha)$$

I have googled and searched on Stack Exhange but found nothing. I hope someone can explain how those two equal each other.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1292/409), and take $\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: You can also use De Moivre's formula

Comment: Also: ["Using the unit circle to prove the double angle formulas for sine and cosine?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136774/409)

Comment: You don’t need dollar signs around each individual math symbol.

Comment: @Damien I like the way you think, but if you don't know the angle addition rules, I am not sure you are ready for De Moivre's law.

Comment: Most of these trig identities can be derived rather quickly using the definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$ from a *complex number* perspective instead of the usual geometric perspective, something which sadly is not taught early enough in my opinion (*not least of all in part due to students fear of complex numbers in the first place*).  You should know that $\sin(z) = \dfrac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}$ and that $\cos(z) = \dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$.  Taking these forms of the expressions and comparing $2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)$ to $\sin(2\alpha)$ should give the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Here is one visualization.

The area of the red triangle is $\frac 12 bh$

the base is $1,$ the height is $\sin 2a$

$A = \frac 12 \sin 2a$

But is can also be decomposed into 2 congruent right triangles with legs $\cos a, \sin a$

$A = \cos a\sin a$

$\frac 12 \sin 2a = \cos a\sin a\\
\sin 2a = 2\cos a\sin a$

Here is another.

[image]

The hypotenuse of the triangle with vertexes $(-1,0), (\cos 2a, \sin 2a)$ is $2\cos a$

$\sin a = \frac {\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \frac {\sin 2a}{2\cos a}\\
2\sin a\cos a = \sin 2a$

Or you can be really boring and say that is falls out of the angle addition rules

$\sin 2a = \sin (a+a) = \sin a\cos a + \cos a\sin a$

Comment: Very pretty indeed, ***+1, endorsed!!!***

Comment: +1

Thanks I know understand where its from. However could you quickly explain how cos(a)*sin(a)= A 

Thanks again

Comment: We can look at the red area as 2 right triangles each with legs $\cos a, \sin a$  or as an isosceles triangle with base $2\sin a$ and altitude $\cos a$ if you prefer.  If you think of it as 2 right triangles then the area is $2(\frac 12 \sin a\cos a)$ or one isosceles triangle $\frac12 (2\sin a)(\cos a)$

Comment: ok. If we multiply in then 2(1/2 sin(a) cos(a) ) it would be sin(a)cos(a) because 2*1/2 gives one ?

Comment: @Hamilton Yes, that's it. Just twice the area of one small triangle.

Comment: Trig identities are *always* much friendlier in visual form! (OK, now sonene will provide a counterexample).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Consider the semicircle over the diameter $[AB]$ of radius 1 and center $E$. Let $C$ be an arbitrary point on the semicircle and $D$ the foot of the altitude of the side $[AB]$ in the triangle $\Delta ABC$. Denote furthermore by $\alpha$ the angle $\angle BAC$. It follows that $\angle BEC=2\alpha$.

By the definition of the sine and cosine $$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{[CB]}{[AB]}$$
$$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{[AC]}{[AB]}$$ Thus $$\sin(\alpha)·\cos(\alpha)=\frac{[CB]·[AC]}{[AB]^2}$$

Now, since $[CD]·[AB]=[AC]·[CB]$ (different ways to get the area of $\Delta ABC$)

$$\sin(\alpha)·\cos(\alpha)=\frac{[CB]·[AC]}{[AB]^2}=\frac{[CD]}{[AB]}=\frac{[CD]}{2}$$ $$\Rightarrow 2·\sin(\alpha)·\cos(\alpha)=[CD]$$

Finally $$\sin(\angle BEC)=\sin(2\alpha)=\frac{[CD]}{[EC]}=[CD] \Rightarrow \sin(2\alpha)=2·\sin(\alpha)·\cos(\alpha)$$

Answer (score 2):

This follows directly from the well-known angle-addition formula for $\sin$:

$\sin(\alpha + \beta) = (\sin \alpha)(\cos \beta) + (\sin \beta)(\cos \alpha); \tag 1$

by taking $\alpha = \beta$:

$\sin 2 \alpha =  (\sin \alpha)(\cos \alpha) + (\sin \alpha)(\cos \alpha) = 2(\sin \alpha)(\cos \alpha); \tag 2$

see [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).

This formula and others may also be derived from the Euler identity

$e^{i\phi} = \cos \phi + i \sin \phi \tag 3$

by taking $\phi = \alpha + \beta$; we obtain

$\cos (\alpha + \beta) + i \sin( \alpha + \beta) = e^{i(\alpha + \beta)} = e^{i\alpha}e^{i\beta} = (\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha)(\cos \beta + i\sin \beta)$
$= (\cos \alpha)(\cos \beta) - (\sin \alpha)(\sin \beta) + i ((\sin \alpha)(\cos \beta) + (\sin \beta)(\cos \alpha)) , \tag 4$

and look at the real and imaginary parts.

and

Comment: ok. I got how you got (2) but now but I  dont understand how you got (1). How does sin go into cos?

Comment: @Hamzalihi:  check out the link to the wiki page.  It explains everything.  Formula (1) may be had geometrically, or by using the Euler formula as I did here.  Cheers!