# I need help solving: $\cos(4x)=\sin(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

In need of help solving the equation; $\cos(4x)=\sin(2x)$. I have tried re-writing $\sin(2x)$, but I'm stuck on what to do with $\cos(4x)$

Comment: Please show all the steps.

Comment: Can I re-write sin(4x) as sin(2x+2x)?

Comment: Trick is simple. Pull in big fish with smaller worm on tackle. Dont sub-express $2u$ with $u$ but express $4u$ in terms of $2u$...Somehow getting along the job wont take you anywhere..  $ \sin_{2x}=u ,\, \cos (4u)=1- 2 u^2,\, 2u^2+u-1=0,\,$ factorize $ (2 u -1)(u+1) =0,\quad u= \frac12,-1; u= \pi/6,5 \pi/6... \pi,2\pi $ &c.

Answer (score 2):

## Hint:

$\cos 4x = 1- 2\sin^2 (2x)$

Substitute this and solve the quadratic in $\sin 2x$.

Alternatively, write $\sin(2x)$ as $\cos(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-2x)$  and then use the general formula for $\cos x = \cos \alpha$ i.e. $x= 2n\pi \pm \alpha$

Comment: How did you get to cos 4x = 1- 2sin^2 (2x) ?

Comment: @Michael.W Because $\sin^2a+\cos^2a=1$

Comment: @Michael.W See the proofs of the double angle formulas [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126894/how-to-derive-a-double-angle-identity?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @ Micheal. W Please learn up all the trig double angle formulas

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\cos(x)-\sin(y)=2 \sin \left(-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

In general: $$\cos\alpha=\cos\beta\iff\alpha=\pm\beta+2n\pi\text{ where }n\in\mathbb Z\tag1$$

Now observe that $$\cos4x=\sin2x=\cos\left(\frac12\pi-2x\right)$$ and apply $(1)$ with $\alpha=4x$ and $\beta=\frac12\pi-2x$.